# Google Maps API Street Highlight

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I noticed a specific effect when I search Google for a road without the street number, where the static map thumbnail is centered on the street, and the street is highlighted with a red border. Here is my query; you'll see the map before the search results.

[Wilson Rd 08012](http://www.google.com/search?q=wilson%20rd%2008012)

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this effect via the Google Static Maps API? Ideally where I could just pass in the street and zip to reproduce that search image. I know there are other questions on here asking how to use street data to plot a line over the map, but I'm curious if anyone knows how to get Google to do what it's already doing, but programmatically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Static Map API is documented: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ and currently road styles don't include this.

However, features are often added to Google Maps first and do find their way from there into their APIs. But they never announce timescales or what's coming up until it's done. Personally I hope this is optional.